# Facebook FQL Query, searching on non-indexable item

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, locale, facebook-fql

I would like to generate a list of facebook user id's of people who are not in the United States. Rather than iterating through a list of user id's and checking each locale, I would like to do an FQL query. I attempted to execute this statement:

SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE locale != "en_US"

However, when I make the query, I recieve the response:

(code 604): Your statement is not indexable.

This is because locale is not an indexable field. Do any of you know what I can do to get around this? Or perhaps another way of doing this entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It says "Your *statement* is not indexable." That means, you can't just use any query (like, extreme case, `SELECT uid, name FROM user` to get all facebook users) that does not conform. Only queries that include WHERE on fields that are indexable can be used. It's a policy, you can not circumvent it.

Comment: Alright, then is it possible to have an indexable field in conjunction with a non-indexable field?

Comment: Yes, sure, just an indexable one must be present.